# Android Unity Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor, unity-editor

I created a game on unity 
I tried building it for Android. After building I checked the folder where I built the game and I couldn’t find it there.  Tried it in different folders still the same. 
Anyone with how to fix should help me out please.

Comment: Any build errors in the console?

Comment: @Iggy when I was building it said I should update to the latest API level which was 26 but the one I had in my pc was level 23. Then they gave an option to use latest installed and I clicked on that and the game was built on API 23. But I couldn’t still find it

Comment: For your second compile, where there any build errors? If not, it should result in the message "Succeeded" or similar. Does it have that?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen there was no succeeded message shown. It finished and didn’t show anything. Don’t know what’s wrong